# .Net web architecture literature

Tags: .net, security, design-patterns, code-reuse

Can somebody please advise a very advanced book on the architecture of the web application development, preferably in .Net

I'm interested in patterns and designs, code security and re-usability

I have studied a variety of books, but they all seem to be for beginner/intermediate levels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look here at the microsoft patterns and practices.  This should help you out.
[Home](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/default.aspx)

They have best practices for the Architecture, Security, Logging as well as Software factories which put there best practices into use.

Answer (score 1):

I shall suggest you to read the guidelines published by Microsoft Patterns and Practices. Go to MS P&P site and collect all best practices. You can see the complete  catalogue here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/bb190351.aspx

Answer (score 0):

NDepend documentation comes with some pretty cool and advanced online blog posts, articles and white books concerning architecture of .NET code:

[Advices on partitioning code through .NET assemblies](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/12/08/advices-on-partitioning-code-through-net-assemblies.aspx)

[Control Components Dependencies to gain Clean Architecture](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=ControllingDependencies)

[Re-factoring, Re-Structuring and the cost of Levelizing](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2009/02/15/re-factoring-re-structuring-and-the-cost-of-levelizing.aspx)

[Evolutionary Design and Acyclic componentization](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2009/02/22/evolutionary-design-and-acyclic-componentization.aspx)

[Layering, the Level metric and the Discourse of Method](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/02/10/layering-the-level-metric-and-the-discourse-of-method.aspx)

[Fighting Fabricated Complexity](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2009/06/28/fighting-fabricated-complexity.aspx)